# Big Query syntax to generate columns from specific rows

Tags: sql, database, syntax, google-bigquery, database-schema

I've been grappling with this all day and can't seem to find the right solution. My data has the following structure:

```
dauid       question    total
------------------------------
35200004    8           300.0    
35200004    9           500.0    
35200005    8           400.0    
35200005    9           600.0    
35200006    8           900.0    
35200006    9           1200.0
```

I'd like to produce the following output:

```
dauid       total_8    total_9   normalized_total
----------------------------------------------------
35200004    300.0      500.0     (total_8 / total_9)
35200005    400.0      600.0     
35200006    900.0      1200.0
```

I can live without the normalized total but I'd really like a way to get the different groups in the question column out as unique columns per dauid field. I've been messing around with the various examples I've uncovered but can't seem to get what I need.

**Edit:**

The values of 8 and 9 are not fixed, this was just an example. Each dauid has 450 corresponding questions and the table is a few million rows. I need a way to be able to selectively query for two or more of these rows and then build each such row as a column.

**Edit #2:**

To add more context, this is the type of query I'm making:

```
SELECT dauid, question, total, male, female
FROM [canada_census_2011.ontario] 
WHERE csdname CONTAINS 'Toronto'
AND (REGEXP_MATCH(question, r'(^9$)') OR REGEXP_MATCH(question, r'(^8$)') ) 
GROUP BY dauid, question, total, male, female
ORDER BY dauid;
```

**Edit #3:**
Excellent, thanks to Pentium10, the final query looks like:

```
select dauid,
sum(if(REGEXP_MATCH(question, r'(^8$)'),total,0)) as total_8,
sum(if(REGEXP_MATCH(question, r'(^9$)'),total,0)) as total_9,
sum(if(REGEXP_MATCH(question, r'(^8$)'),total,0))/sum(if(REGEXP_MATCH(question, r'(^9$)'),total,0)) as normalized
FROM [canada_census_2011.ontario] 
WHERE csdname CONTAINS 'Toronto'
AND (REGEXP_MATCH(question, r'(^9$)') OR REGEXP_MATCH(question, r'(^8$)') )
GROUP BY dauid
```

Comment: the value of question is 8 and 9 are fixed or it could be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample query produces what you want

```
select dauid,
sum(if(question=8,total,0)) as total_8,
sum(if(question=9,total,0)) as total_9,
sum(if(question=8,total,0))/sum(if(question=9,total,0)) as normalized
 from
(select 35200004 as dauid,  8 as question,           300.0     as total),
(select 35200004 as dauid,  9 as question,           500.0     as total),
(select 35200005 as dauid,  8 as question,           400.0     as total),
(select 35200005 as dauid,  9 as question,           600.0     as total),
(select 35200006 as dauid,  8 as question,           900.0     as total),
(select 35200006 as dauid,  9 as question,           1200.0 as total)
group by dauid
```

it returns

```
+---+----------+---------+---------+--------------------+---+
|   |  dauid   | total_8 | total_9 |     normalized     |   |
+---+----------+---------+---------+--------------------+---+
| 1 | 35200004 | 300.0   | 500.0   | 0.6                |   |
| 2 | 35200005 | 400.0   | 600.0   | 0.6666666666666666 |   |
| 3 | 35200006 | 900.0   | 1200.0  | 0.75               |   |
+---+----------+---------+---------+--------------------+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, excited to be making progress here. Now how would I build a query with this example? I'll edit my question.

Comment: You need to build from your coding language, you cannot generate SQL language using SQL language.

Comment: Yes, let me rephrase that. I know what to do once I get the results back. I mean how do I use SQL language to replace the selects you've got between <from> and <group by dauid> so that I'm not directly referencing known values? Eg, instead of "(select 35200004 as dauid,  8 as question..." what's the proper syntax to do iterate this for all dauid's that meet my search criteria.

Comment: Eg, in the following query? "SELECT dauid, question, total FROM [canada_census_2011.ontario] WHERE csdname CONTAINS 'Toronto' AND (REGEXP_MATCH(question, r'(^9$)') OR REGEXP_MATCH(question, r'(^8$)') ) GROUP BY dauid, question, total ORDER BY dauid;"

Comment: You place there your own query. (select dauid, question, total from mytable).

Comment: I just used the static query to answer the problem, but there you can place your own subquery to select and filter your results.